# preact: OnChange doesn't work with input files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I've encountered with a problem that `onChange` event in `preact` doesn't work. In `react` everything works fine though. `onInput` doesn't work either.

Example of dumb code that must work (`preact` + `typescript`)

```
export class Download extends React.Component<DownloadProps, {}> {
  constructor(props: DownloadProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imgSrc: ''
    };
  }

  public componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('did2')
  }
    public render() {
      console.log('render', this.state);
      return <div className={s.root}>
        <input className='fileInput' type='file' onChange={() => { this.handleImageChange() }}  />
        <div className={s.comment}>Upload</div>
      </div>;
    }

  private handleImageChange() {
      this.setState({imgSrc: '30'})
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont know about typescript, but as i saw this code: http://blog.wolksoftware.com/working-with-react-and-typescript,
i think instead of `function` keyword use `public`

Comment: @MayankShukla, `handleImageChange` isn't part of a `Download class`. I can use `private handleImageChange` and put it in the class but it's not a solution

Comment: i think u forgot to write `this`, try this: `this.handleImageChange.bind(this)`

Comment: @MayankShukla, I've tried, doesn't work. Edit code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in preact-compat 3.13.1, released 2 days ago:

https://github.com/developit/preact-compat/releases/tag/3.13.1